# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am getting a value from `<input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">`

Based on the inputted string for `{{myValue}}`, actions are made. But if the user types uppercase string then they will get incorrect action.

```
if (this.myValue === 'abc') {
    alert('lowercase str');
}
```

Before the above code, I have this but I get the "cannot read property etc":

```
var str = this.myValue;
var res = str.toLowerCase();

if (res === 'abc') {
    alert('lowercase str');
}
```

Is there a correct way for this? Thanks

**Edit:**

```
<dom-module id='my-app'>
 <template>
   <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">
 </template>
<script>
 Polymer({
  is: 'my-app',
   properties: {
    myValue: {
     type: String,
     observer: "selectionChanged"
   }
  },
 selectionChanged: function () {
    var str = this.myValue;
    var res = str.toLowerCase();

    if (res === 'abc') {
        alert('lowercase str');
    }
 }
 });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: The error says `str` is undefined and not a string. We can't help more because you didn't post how `this.myValue` is set.

Comment: @Oriol I have added more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to duplicate the problem with the code posted in the question. The myValue object should be included as a property, per Dev's answer. With that fix a button is unnecessary and everything seems to work fine.

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
<template>
    <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-app',
        properties: {
        myValue: {
            type: String,
            observer: "selectionChanged"
        }
        },
        selectionChanged: function() {
            var str = this.myValue;
            var res = str.toLowerCase();

            if (res === 'abc') {
                alert('lowercase str');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

edit:

Also, you could just add an empty string as a default value.

```
myValue: {
    type: String,
    observer: "selectionChanged",
    value: ""
}
```

Comment: I keep getting, in the console, `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. Also the page get blank. Im lost.

Comment: What version of polymer are you using? I have 1.0.6

Comment: 1.0 Is there a 1.0.6 polymer?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if that's what causing the problem though. Are you using the example code you posted? Or is it throwing the error in some other usage?

You can also try just adding a default value. See edited answer

Comment: I'm using same code. Now I get `TypeError: $(...).toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: @miyamoto so sorry about that. I had a `.toLowerCase()'` somewhere else in my code that was causing the issue. Also, I had to have `value: ''` for your answer to work. Thanks, and thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure myValue property is defined on your polymer element. This code works for me:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/iron-input/iron-input.html">

<dom-module id="x-sample">
     <template>
         <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">
         <button on-click="updateValue">myValue.toLowerCase()</button>
     </template>
     <script>
         Polymer({
             is: 'x-sample',
             properties: {
                myValue: String
             },
             updateValue: function (e) {
                var str = this.myValue;
                var res = str.toLowerCase();
                alert(res);
             }
         });
     </script>
 </dom-module>
```

---

**UPDATE**

You need to define your properties (myValue) inside the 'properties' object, not on the root object.

Comment: Thanks. While that may work, I do not need a button. Is that the only way to make the string lowercase? No way of adding `{{myValue}}` to a variable?

Comment: Yes, I have. same issue.